# How can I use Fn::GetAttr only when the resource exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

I'm making one main stack and two nested stack.
The first nested stack is a stack which creates Lambda.
And the second nested stack creates Apigateway.

When making the Apigateway I send some Lambda outputs to the Apigateway template.
But some Lambda Outputs don't get created in some conditions.

So when I use `Fn::GetAttr` to send some outputs to the Apigateway template. I get an error because the output doesn't exist.

[Lambda Template (Nested Stack)]

Because of the condition `conditionNeedMock` the MockServerArn output wasn't created.

```
...
Outputs:
  MockServerArn:
    Condition: conditionNeedMock
    Description: lambdaMock function Arn
    Value: !GetAttr lambdaMock.Arn
...
```

[Main Template]

`LambdaStack.Ouputs.MockserverArn` wasn't created so I get an error when using `!GetAttr`.

```
...
Resources:
  LambdaStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    ...

  ApiGatewayStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn: LambdaStack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: apigateway.yml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 20
      Parameters:
        paramMockServerArn: !GetAtt LambdaStack.Outputs.MockServerArn
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that could possibly work (without introducing custom resources) is if `conditionNeedMock` is also in the root stack:

```
paramMockServerArn: !If [conditionNeedMock, !GetAtt LambdaStack.Outputs.MockServerArn, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking like checking nulls in programming. There was a simple solution but I thought very difficultly.